# Pre order generic list C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a sorted list in C#, but when I inserting a item not sorting after insert all.

Neither `SortedList` nor `Dictionary` are suitable because I may have duplicate keys.

For example:

```
list.Insert(1001, v1);
list.Insert(1002, v2);
list.Insert(1002, v3);
list.Insert(1003, v4);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to write a custom comparer which would allow duplicate keys in your collection:

```
public class DuplicateKeyComparer<TKey> : IComparer<TKey> where TKey : IComparable
{
    public int Compare(TKey x, TKey y)
    {
        var res = x.CompareTo(y);
        return res == 0 ? 1 : res;
    }
}
```

and then use a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var comparer = new DuplicateKeyComparer<int>();
var list = new SortedList<int, string>(comparer);
list.Add(1001, "v1");
list.Add(1002, "v2");
list.Add(1002, "v3");
list.Add(1003, "v4");
```

Obviously there are culprits with this approach that you should be aware of - you will never be able to remove any key from this collection. So if you intend to use `list.Remove(1002)` as an example, then you will need an alternative approach.